# Need to look through a class object without changing it

Tags: python, dictionary

Alright, lets suppose I have a class called Tab and that class has a method that takes in keys and values of dictionaries and and makes it into a huge dictionary.

```
class Tab():

def __init__(self):
    if not 'table' in dir(self):
        self._table = {}        

def add_table(self, key, value):    
    self._table[key] = value
```

Now if i were to have a function and a dictionary

```
dic = {'A': ['A', 'B','C'], 'B':['D', 'E','F']}
def read_table():
    table = Tab()
    for key in dic:
        table.add_table(key, dic[key])
    return table
test = read_table()
```

And if I were to run this it would run fine, but if I did this,

```
new_test = test['A']
```

It would crash. I know I can fix this by converting the object back into a dictionary, but i need the type to be the Tab class(the one i defined earlier).

How can I do this?

Comment: what do you mean `crash` ? Do you get error message ? Always show full error message (Traceback) in question.

Comment: see [__getitem__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) and [__setitem__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a `Tab` instance behave like a dictionary, you can override `__getitem__(self, item)`, `__setitem__(self, key, value)` and `__repr__(self)` methods within `Tab` class:

```
class Tab():

    def __init__(self):
        if not 'table' in dir(self):
            self._table = {}

    def add_table(self, key, value):
        self._table[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._table[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._table[key] = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._table.__repr__()

dic = {'A': ['A', 'B','C'], 'B':['D', 'E','F']}
...
# read_table() function declaration (omitted)
...
test = read_table()
new_test = test['A']       # accessing dict element
test['C'] = ['G','H','I']  # setting a new dict element

print(new_test)
print(test)       # printing Tab instance as a dict
print(type(test))
```

The output(sequentially):

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
{'B': ['D', 'E', 'F'], 'A': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'C': ['G', 'H', 'I']}
<class '__main__.Tab'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you overcomplicate things? Why not inherit `dict` object, and using `update` method.

Or even better to inherit [`UserDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userdict-objects) from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) module.

```
from collections import UserDict

class Tab(UserDict):
    pass

dic = {'A': ['A', 'B','C'], 'B':['D', 'E','F']}

def read_table(dic):
    table = Tab()
    table.update(dic)
    return table

read_table(dic).data['A']
```

And it's better to pass obj in `read_table` function.